# JS: How to change image orientation from horizontal to vertical that were fetched from an API with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, api, radio-button, orientation

My page currently shows 5 images based on what the user searches. I'm having trouble making the Horizontal and Vertical radio buttons change the orientation of how the images are displayed. These are my HTML and JS files so far, any help would be appreciated.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Lab 5</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

    <header class="bg-info p-4 text-center">
      <h1> Pixabay Image Search </h1>
    </header>
    <section class="m-5">
      <input id="userInput" type="text">
    </section>
    <section>
      <input type="radio" name="orientation" value="vertical" id="Vertical"> Vertical
      <input type="radio" name="orientation" value="horizontal" id="Horizontal"> Horizontal
    </section>
    <button id="searchButton">Search</button>
    
    <div id="pictures">
      
    </div>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="305" height="312" id="myPicture" alt="some image">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my JS so far:

```
document.querySelector("#searchButton")
  .addEventListener("click", displayImages);

function displayImages (){
  //alert("hello");
  let search = document.querySelector("#userInput").value;

  let orientation = document.querySelector("input[name=orientation]:checked").value;

  //alert(orientation);

  let url = `placeholderapi{orientation}`;
  console.log(url);
  
  fetch(url)
.then( function(response) { return response.json()} )
.then( function(data) {
   //console.log(data);
document.querySelector("#pictures").innerHTML = "";

   for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     document.querySelector("#pictures").innerHTML += `<img src="${data.hits[i].webformatURL}" width="100px">`;
   }

});
}
```

Comment: Hey, could you please provide the html code for this

Comment: Of course, I just added it.